# Setting a NSManagedObject as a value in a NSDictionary giving "escapeString" not recognized error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmanagedobject

I have a `NSManagedObject` that stores some data. I convert that data into a `NSDictionary` to upload via XML to our server. The server will reply if it was successful and with information I need to update the `NSManagedObject` with.

My thought was to add the `NSManagedObject` in the `NSDictionary` so I have a easy reference to it. The issue is when I try to upload it through my XMLRPC, it gives me the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Scouting escapedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2297f8d0'
```

I do not have anything named `escapedString`, so I am at a lost to what is happening. It will happen regardless of the type of `NSManagedObject` I assign as the value.

Code:

```
id result = [self.serverCall XMLRPCCall:API_SAVE_OBJECT withObjects:@[year, dictionaries]];
```

Year is a `NSNumber` and dictionaries is an array of dictionaries.

Here is how the server call is made:

```
-(id)XMLRPCCall:(NSString *)methodName withObjects:(NSArray *)parametersArray
{
    NSString *authServer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?idtoken=%@", self.API, self.IDToken];

    XMLRPCRequest *requestCall = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:authServer]];
    [requestCall setMethod:methodName withParameters:parametersArray];
    [requestCall setTimeoutInterval:10];

    return [self executeXMLRPCERequest:requestCall];
}

-(id)executeXMLRPCERequest:(XMLRPCRequest *)request {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DisableOfflineButton" object:nil];

    NSError *myError;

    XMLRPCResponse *serverResponse = [XMLRPCConnection sendSynchronousXMLRPCRequest:request error:&myError];

    if (myError) {
        NSLog(@"myError: %@ [myError userInfo]: %@", myError, [myError userInfo]);

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NETWORK_ERROR object:nil];

        return NETWORK_ERROR;
    }

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = FALSE;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"EnableOfflineButton" object:nil];

    if ([[serverResponse object] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]
        && [[serverResponse object] objectForKey:FAULT_CODE]) {
        DLog(@"fault code found");
        if ([[[serverResponse object] objectForKey:FAULT_STRING] isEqualToString:@"Token is not valid.  Destroying token."]) {
            DLog(@"invalid token");
            self.IDToken = nil;
            self.API = nil;

            [self.delegate forceLogout];
        }
    }
    else {
        Defaults *defaults = [Defaults MR_findFirst];

        defaults.tokenIDDate = [NSDate date];
    }

    return [serverResponse object];
}
```

Any ideas whats causing the error?

Comment: You really should be saving the `objectID` or some other unique key that represents the `NSManagedObject` instead of saving the whole object.

Comment: Do you filter the keys of the dictionary that the XML serialisation processes or do you allow it to process all keys?

Comment: @Wain I do not filter the keys. I use that method to upload 15+ different API calls and filtering it would be bothersome. I did filter out the `NSManagedObject`s and store in a temp array before making the call. Its a work around, but it works.

Comment: @Hyperbole I tried setting the value to the objectID, but I get the error: `-[_NSObjectID_64_1 escapedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x26951670
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSObjectID_64_1 escapedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x26951670'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with adding extra data to the dictionary is that the XML serialiser will try to process it. To avoid that you want to store the managed object (or its identifier) somewhere else. This could be in another property / array / dictionary. Or, you could use associated objects (`objc_setAssociatedObject`).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Scouting escapedString]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2297f8d0'

So you need to set an exception breakpoint to understand where the problem is. Go to the **breakpoint navigator** in the left column of the Xcode window, press + at the bottom left, and choose **Add Exception Breakpoint**. Reproduce the problem, and the debugger will stop in the location where the exception happens. Then follow the stack trace down to your own code, and you should have (or begin to have) an understanding of why the exception happened.